# I need help mixing C++ code and Objective-C code

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, class-extensions

I am writing a device driver for a Blackmagic Design AV device in XCode, and I'm having trouble including BMD's SyncController class from their abbreviated sample code (below) into my purely Objective-C project.

Their DecklinkAPI.h file is rich in C++ code, so when I try include this header file as-is in a an Objective-C class, the compiler chokes deep in the API include: *Unknown type name 'class'; did you mean 'Class'?*

I have tried to to bundle up the C++ bits into a Obj-C class extension as noted [here](http://www.philjordan.eu/article/mixing-objective-c-c++-and-objective-c++), but without much success.  I've never done any C++ programming (and have never used Obj-C class extensions), so this is new territory for me.

I'm not sure if I need to create an additional wrapper class for my SyncController object, or whether I can just do a class extension on this one and shuffle the C++ bits into the .mm file.

I would like to be able to do a `#include "SyncController.h"` (or its wrapper) in an Objective-C class without having the compiler choke.

**Any assistance in doing so would be much appreciated.**

First up, here is my current SyncController.h file:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "DeckLinkAPI.h"  // this is rich in C++ code

class PlaybackDelegate;

@interface SyncController : NSObject {
    PlaybackDelegate*           playerDelegate;

    IDeckLink*                  deckLink;
    IDeckLinkOutput*            deckLinkOutput;
}

- (void)scheduleNextFrame:(BOOL)prerolling;
- (void)writeNextAudioSamples;

@end

class PlaybackDelegate : public IDeckLinkVideoOutputCallback, public IDeckLinkAudioOutputCallback
{
    SyncController*             mController;
    IDeckLinkOutput*            mDeckLinkOutput;

public:
    PlaybackDelegate (SyncController* owner, IDeckLinkOutput* deckLinkOutput);

    // IUnknown needs only a dummy implementation
    virtual HRESULT     QueryInterface (REFIID iid, LPVOID *ppv)    {return E_NOINTERFACE;}
    virtual ULONG       AddRef ()                                   {return 1;}
    virtual ULONG       Release ()                                  {return 1;}

    virtual HRESULT     ScheduledFrameCompleted (IDeckLinkVideoFrame* completedFrame, BMDOutputFrameCompletionResult result);
    virtual HRESULT     ScheduledPlaybackHasStopped ();
    virtual HRESULT     RenderAudioSamples (bool preroll);
};

void    ScheduleNextVideoFrame (void);
```

Next up, here is my (simplified) SyncController.mm file:

```
#import <CoreFoundation/CFString.h>
#import "SyncController.h"

@implementation SyncController

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
}

- (void)scheduleNextFrame:(BOOL)prerolling
{
}

- (void)writeNextAudioSamples
{
}

@end

PlaybackDelegate::PlaybackDelegate (SyncController* owner, IDeckLinkOutput* deckLinkOutput)
{
    mController = owner;
    mDeckLinkOutput = deckLinkOutput;
}

HRESULT PlaybackDelegate::ScheduledFrameCompleted (IDeckLinkVideoFrame* completedFrame, BMDOutputFrameCompletionResult result)
{
    [mController scheduleNextFrame:NO];
    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT     PlaybackDelegate::ScheduledPlaybackHasStopped ()
{
    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT     PlaybackDelegate::RenderAudioSamples (bool preroll)
{
    [mController writeNextAudioSamples];
    if (preroll)
        mDeckLinkOutput->StartScheduledPlayback(0, 100, 1.0);

    return S_OK;
}
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: As noted in the post, I get a problem with
  "Unknown type name 'class'; did you mean 'Class'?"

Comment: Are you using an older version of Xcode or gcc, or are you targeting 32-bit OS X?  That will affect how you use class extensions.

Comment: Darren, I am targeting OSX 64-bit with Xcode 5.1.1 and OSX10.9.4.

Comment: @zzyzy Using class extensions should be fairly straight forward, then.  You simply move the CPP header, CPP instance variables and CPP class declarations to your .mm file.  What problem were you having using class extensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried to to bundle up the C++ bits into a Obj-C class extension as noted here, but without much success.

If you're targeting 64-bit, the class extension method should be fairly simple.

The following is equivalent to the code you've post, but moves all of the C++ declarations to a separate header:

SyncController.h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface SyncController : NSObject
- (void)scheduleNextFrame:(BOOL)prerolling;
- (void)writeNextAudioSamples;
@end
```

SyncController_CPP.h

```
#import "SyncController.h"
#include "DeckLinkAPI.h"

class PlaybackDelegate;

@interface SyncController() {
    PlaybackDelegate* playerDelegate;
    IDeckLink* deckLink;
    IDeckLinkOutput* deckLinkOutput;
}
@end

class PlaybackDelegate  ...
{
    ...
}
```

SyncController.mm

```
#import "SyncController_CPP.h"

@implementation SyncController
...
@end

PlaybackDelegate::PlaybackDelegate (SyncController* owner, IDeckLinkOutput* deckLinkOutput)
{
    mController = owner;
    mDeckLinkOutput = deckLinkOutput;
}

// etc..
```

Any other ObjC classes that need access to `SyncController` will import "SyncController.h".  Any other ObjC++ classes can import either "SyncController.h" or "SyncController_CPP.h"

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer, however errors like:

*Unknown type name 'class'; did you mean 'Class'?*

Is a classic issue with Objective-C++ where an **Objective-C implementation file is seeing a C++ header file**.

I can only provide *advice* about how to avoid it as you didn't post the complete build output.

- Don't put C++ headers is the pre-compiled header.
- Try to only include C++ headers within Objective-C++ implementation files and not in their counterpart header file which might, in turn, be included into an Objective-C file.
- Hide the use of C++ from any header files, for example using private instance variables:

  ```
  #import <vector>
  @implementation MyObjCppClass {
      std::vector<int> _stuff;
  }

  - (id)init {
      ...
  }

  @end
  ```
- If you are mixing Objective-C and Objective-C++ then you might find you need to provide Objective-C wrappers to C++ classes (which look from the outside as Objective-C but are actually implemented in Objective-C++).

Comment: Thank you for the advice.  I'm aware that I need to move everything after the interface declaration in my SyncController.h file into a .mm file.  This will, in effect, prevent C++ headers from appearing in Obj-C implementation files.  I think I'm pretty clear on hiding C++ via instance variables -- but, given that there's a Playback delegate in the API, I was unsure how to make that happen with Obj-C wrappers.

Comment: Further to this, is what I've provided in the code above sufficient for the ability to rewrite it in a Obj-C wrapper object?  I was hoping so. Again, I'm not proficient in C++.  Cheers.  Thanks again for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Rename your .m files (objective-c) to .mm (objective-c++). this should allow you to then mix objc and c++ by including c++ headers and referencing c++ code from your objc.

---EDIT---

Any header file you include from objective-c must contain only objective-c. Remove any c++ from the header in your wrapper class to get the other objc classes to build. In modern objc, you can split your ivars between the .h and .m files; keep all your methods in the .h for other objc classes to use, and declare your c++ ivars in the .mm. Stick your c++ delegate class in its own .h that is only included from the .mm wrapper.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I'm working on an Obj-C project with about 130 .m files contained therein so far, and only one .mm file to contend with at this point.  I'm trying to avoid having to go that route.

Answer (score 1):

Use `#if __cplusplus`.

For example,

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

#if __cplusplus
#import "DeckLinkAPI.h"  // this is rich in C++ code
#endif // __cplusplus

@interface SyncController : NSObject {
    void* playerDelegate; // should be cast as C++ PlaybackDelegate class.
    ...
}
@end

#if __cplusplus
class PlaybackDelegate : public IDeckLinkVideoOutputCallback, public IDeckLinkAudioOutputCallback
{
    ...
};
#endif // __cplusplus
```

The header file can be used with Objective-C and Objective-C++. But you can not use C++ class signature in SyncController Objective-C class declaration in the header. Use `void *` instead of `PlaybackDelegate *` with proper type cast.

Also using `void *` means that C++ stuff in the header is no longer needed.

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface SyncController : NSObject {
    void* playerDelegate; // should be cast as C++ PlaybackDelegate class.
    ...
}
@end
```

In Objective-C++ code,

```
// initialize
syncController.playerDelegate = new PlaybackDelegate();

// use the pointer
PlaybackDelegate *playbackDelegate = (PlaybackDelegate *)syncController.playerDelegate;
```

Comment: Hmmm... this is an attractive alternate solution to using class extensions.

Answer (score 1):

initialize

```
syncController.playerDelegate = new PlaybackDelegate();

// use the pointer
PlaybackDelegate *playbackDelegate = (PlaybackDelegate *)syncController.playerDelegate
```